# What could cause issue with accessing server over vpn

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, juniper

We have two servers at point A, users at point B connect to the servers

We use juniper firewalls to do the VPN,

Server 2 OS was just reinstalled.

Access to server 2 stopped working. Users at point B cant ping Server 2. But server 1 (untouched) still works flawlessly.

What could be the issue

Comment: Please describe your setup in more detail. What kind of connection is this? Over Internet? Give traceroutes, etc.

Comment: yea its over internet.

Comment: @KonradGajewski its a very basic setup i believe. do you think it has to do with a config on the server?

Comment: Can Server 1 ping Server 2?

Comment: @KonradGajewski yes...both servers can ping each other because they are in the same lan...

Comment: Can server 2 ping the router?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26615/discussion-between-konrad-gajewski-and-prince-nnamdi).

Comment: @KonradGajewski yes both servers can ping the gateway / firewall.

Comment: I'm on the chat (link above).

Comment: issue has been resolved. wrong gateway IP was used